# Cannot access radtextbox inside radDock from child

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, raddocking, radtextbox

Here is my `radTextBox` inside `radDock` , I set this in my `ParentPage`

```
   <telerik:RadDockZone ID="ZoneDescription" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" Width="600px">
                <telerik:RadDock ID="DockDescription" runat="server" EnableDrag="false" EnableRoundedCorners="true"
                    Title="Itinerary Description" Width="600px" Skin="Vista" DefaultCommands="None">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="padding-top: 5px;">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtxtDescription" runat="server" Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine">
                            </telerik:RadTextBox>
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </telerik:RadDock>
            </telerik:RadDockZone>
```

From my child Page , I get `rtxtDescription`'s text value likes ,

```
 (((this.Parent.FindControl("ZoneDescription") as RadDockZone).  
 FindControl("DockDescription") as RadDock).  
 FindControl("rtxtDescription") as RadTextBox).Text;
```

and

```
(this.Parent.FindControl("rtxtDescription") as RadTextBox).Text;
```

But both doesn't work , cannot access `rtxtDescription` .
How can I solve it ? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
((ZoneDescription.FindControl("DockDescription") as RadDock).ContentContainer.FindControl("rtxtDescription") as RadTextBox).Text = "Your text here";
```